# The syntax of the open3 command

Tags: perl

According to the [manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html) the syntax of the `IPC::Open3::open3` is

```
$pid = open3(\*CHLD_IN, \*CHLD_OUT, \*CHLD_ERR, 'some cmd and args', 'optarg', ...);
```

I am confused regarding the first three parameters. Are these references to typeglobs?

I tried the following:

1. `my $pid=open3("STDIN", "STDOUT", "STDERR", $cmd);`
2. `my $pid=open3(*STDIN, *STDOUT, *STDERR, $cmd);`
3. `my $pid=open3(\*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR, $cmd);`
4. `my $pid=open3('<&STDIN', '>&STDOUT', '>&STDERR', $cmd);`

but only number 4, seemed to work. According to manual, I thought number 3 should also work. For example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
use IPC::Open3;

my $cmd="sleep 1; echo This STDOUT; sleep 1; echo 'This is STDERR' 1>&2; sleep 1; echo -n 'Reading STDIN: '; read a";

my $pid=open3('<&STDIN', '>&STDOUT', '>&STDERR', $cmd);
say "Waiting for child..";
wait;
say "Done.";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass the strings `'<&STDIN'` and `'>&STDOUT'` then the child process gets a duplicate of your Perl program's own standard input and output handles, and can read and write to and from them without any further intervention.

That is a very diffferent things from specifying filehandles using typeglob references. The `CHLD_OUT` file handle in the documentation is the `STDOUT` for the *child* process and it allows your Perl program to *read* from `CHLD_OUT` so that you can acquire and process the data it is sending. Using `STDOUT` here won't work because it is the *output* file handle for your Perl process. You could, if you really wanted, use `STDIN`, but that would leave you unable to read anything that was originally presented to your standard input.

The equivalent points apply to `CHLD_IN`, which is a handle that you `print` to to send data to the child process. Again, you *could* use `STDOUT` here, but that deprives you of the original standard output channel. In any case you would still have to invent another file handle for `CHLD_ERR`, because you would be *reading* from it to see what the child was sending to its standard error output, and of course you cannot read from `STDERR`.

So the best you could do is to replace

```
open3(\*CHLD_IN, \*CHLD_OUT, \*CHLD_ERR, 'command')
```

with

```
open3(\*STDOUT, \*STDIN, \*CHLD_ERR, 'command')
```

but file handles aren't costly, so why commit yourself to losing your standard input and output? Much better to create three new file handles and work with all six.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation! I think I should get the concept now :)